# MVC model relationships: how to avoid multiple instances of models?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I'm trying to create an MVC application for managing sports teams and players using Zend Framework. A team has a list of players and each player belongs to only one team. The problem I have is with instantiating multiple individual players.

At the moment when I instantiate a single player, a new team object is always created even if I had instantiated a player that belongs to the same team earlier. How could I avoid unnecessary multiple instances that represent the same team? Is there some design pattern or technique that could be used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern that is probably going to be of the most use is the [Identity Map](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityMap.html).

Comment: Thanks! I think this might be the thing I'm looking for. I was already thinking of implementing something similar so this was a nice confirmation that I'm going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty controversial nowadays, but [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) might also be your friend.